# Unknown Video Format

Tags: file-formats

I had a video file named file.mp4. I have tried many codecs/players to open it with no luck.

Finally, I used a hex-editor to open the file, and here is what i have found.

Any suggestions on how I can work with this file?

[image]

Comment: The file type (ftyp) in your header is "isom". Try https://superuser.com/questions/311595/change-mp4-ftyp-from-isom-to-mp42

Comment: Thank you Peter. Please post an answer, so I can flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: It's fine - if I try to post that as an answer, the site comes back with "trivial answer converted to comment". So there you go! Glad that it worked, it was really just a quick look through - I thought there might still be more to it than what I posted.

Comment: Trivial, but very helpful.